# unable to upload image using twitter api

Tags: perl, api, twitter

I am using twitter API provided by `Net::Twitter`([cpan link](http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-4.01007/lib/Net/Twitter.pod)). I am able to post status but unable to upload image.

**Perl code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;

use Net::Twitter;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

# When no authentication is required:
#my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(legacy => 0);
my $consumer_key = "consumerkey";
my $consumer_secret = "consumersecret";
my $token="token";
my $token_secret="tokensecret";

# As of 13-Aug-2010, Twitter requires OAuth for authenticated requests
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits   => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/],
    consumer_key        => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret     => $consumer_secret,
    access_token        => $token,
    access_token_secret => $token_secret,
);
eval { 
#my $result = $nt->update({status=>'some message'}); ##this works fine
my $result = $nt->upload({media=>'/some/path/toimage.jpeg' ,media_data => encode_base64('/some/path/toimage.jpeg')}); #this line produces error
    };

if ( my $err = $@ ) {
    die $@ unless blessed $err && $err->isa('Net::Twitter::Error');

    warn "HTTP Response Code: ", $err->code, "\n",
         "HTTP Message......: ", $err->message, "\n",
         "Twitter error.....: ", $err->error, "\n";
}
```

**Error:**

```
HTTP Response Code: 400

HTTP Message......: Bad Request 

Twitter error.....: media type unrecognized.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspiring from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678794/1848140).

I had done the same in perl something like:

```
my @filename = ('path/to/image.jepg');
my $result = $nt->update_with_media({status=>'hI',media=>\@filename});
```

This worked perfectly. Although only array reference works here.

Note: According to documentation and from @simbabque answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859827/1848140)

> upload    upload(media)
>
> Parameters: media
> Required: media
> **Upload images to twitter without posting them on the timeline**
>
> Returns: Image

Which I guess will only upload but doesnot show on timeline. So I used the `update_with_media` method to post images.

Comment: Ah. I thought you want to just upload.

Comment: may be a bit confusion here, I thought upload will post to timeline initilally, but after I saw your answer and realised what it does and used update_with_media. Anyway I struglled 2hours to get the work done with update_media as there is no proper documentation.

Comment: I see. Glad it works now. :) You could submit a patch to the author and add more documentation. The github repo is linked on CPAN (https://github.com/semifor/Net-Twitter) I'm sure the author appreciates that.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter#upload) is a bit sparse on `upload`, but it does say it needs something called *media*.

> ### upload
>
> ### upload(media)
>
> Parameters: media
>   Required: media
>   Upload images to twitter without posting them on the timeline
>
> Returns: Image

However, directly above [at `update_with_media`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter#update_with_media) it describes an entity *media*.

> The `media[]` parameter is an arrayref with the following
>   interpretation:
>
> ```
> [ $file ]
> [ $file, $filename ]
> [ $file, $filename, Content_Type => $mime_type ]
> [ undef, $filename, Content_Type => $mime_type, Content => $raw_image_data ]
> ```

So based on that I would expect that your upload has to look something like this:

```
my content_of_image_file; # open the file and read its content in binary mode
my $result = $nt->upload([
  undef,
  'filename_as_it_should_appear_on_twitter.jpeg', # this is a guess
  Content_Type => 'image/jpeg',
  Content => encode_base64($content_of_image_file),
]);
```

**Note that I have not tested this.**

Comment: Can you clarify what is binary mode here?

Comment: Okay I tried using binmode while opening the file using this approach but still the same error